# Deregistering Jscripts / CSS From Wordpress Plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

Im not sure if this is an issue with Wordpress 3.0 and changes to function names but as far as I can tell this should remove the jscripts and css from the headers sitewide

add_action('wp_print_scripts','my_deregister_javascript', 100);
function my_deregister_javascript(){

```
    wp_deregister_script('ngg_script');
    wp_deregister_script('thickbox');
```

}

add_action('wp_print_styles','my_deregister_styles', 100);
function my_deregister_styles(){

```
    wp_deregister_style('NextGEN');
    wp_deregister_style('thickbox');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My fault I was calling the action before hte function

Comment: And how do I fix that?